# Multidimensional arrays with only ONE entry

Tags: powershell

I wrote a generic function to call a stored procedure. I tried to use a multidimensional array to pass the parameters. Now it is possible, that the procedure only takes one parameter, so my multidimensional array has also only one parameter. **But the length of such an array is 2**!

```
$MyParameters = ("param1_name", "param1_value")
```

`$MyParameters.Length` returns **2**!! Strange, why? It should return **1**

`$MyParameters` returns correctly:

param1_name
param1_value

If I write:

```
$MyParameters = ("param1_name", "param1_value"), ("param2_name", "param2_value")
```

`$MyParameters.Length` returns **also** 2 which is correct. `$MyParameters` returns correctly all four elements:

param1_name
param1_value
param2_name
param2_value

Any reasons for that? Am I missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jagged PowerShell array is losing a dimension when only one element exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390782/jagged-powershell-array-is-losing-a-dimension-when-only-one-element-exists)

Comment: Related: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64763381/how-to-create-nested-array-and-to-add-array-elements-in-it), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390782/jagged-powershell-array-is-losing-a-dimension-when-only-one-element-exists)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do is creating an **array of multi value object**.

Here is an example to solve that issue:

```
$x = ,("param1","param2","param3")
x.Length
```

Will return **1** which is correct for your issue.

```
$x = ,("param1","param2","param3"),("param1","param2","param3")
x.Length
```

Will return **2**

```
$x = ,("param1","param2","param3"),("param1","param2","param3")
x[0].Length
```

will return **1**, thats because $x[0] is array with one element.

In addition, If you would like to create an Array of Arrays this is the way to do it:

```
$x = @("param1","param2","param3"),@("param1","param2","param3")
$x.Length
#2
$x[0].Length
#3
```

Comment: *will return 1, thats because $x[0] is not an array - it is an object* Not true, `$x[0]` is array with one element. Simply do `$x[0].GetType().FullName` and you will see `System.Object[]`.

Comment: Cool, adding the comma IN FRONT!

Comment: Shouldn't `x.Length` be `$x.Length`?